# QField crashing when new point data added with error "Feature 0 could not be fetched after commit"

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have an issue with QField and am not sure how to troubleshoot it. Sometimes when creating a new point (after entering its attributes and pressing the check mark to save it), QField freezes with an alarm in the upper right corner that reads "Feature 0 could not be fetched after commit".

The app has to be closed and restarted to make it work. It seems a bit random on when this occurs (e.g. I can re-enter the exact same information into the attributes form and it will work the second time; it will freeze several times in a row and then work fine for hours).

Any ideas on how to start looking into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the point layer that was crashing in QField, in the QGIS desktop project I had checked "Show Feature Count" in the layer menu. When I unchecked that box in QGIS desktop (to stop showing the feature count), that fixed the issue in QField (after saving and repackaging it, of course).

To go further, I also had rule-based symbology based on a feature's update status, so there was a submenu with feature counts. My project would crash on the updating of a point as well, then. This makes me think the bug has something to do with tracking the changes in the database and not working with the rolling feature count.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the feature count was on for some of my layers, but (wrongfully!) assumed it couldn't be that.